# Genius Math Tool: How to display fraction answers as decimal?

Tags: math, floating-point, fractions

When I do some calculations with genius I get the answers as fractions. For example:

```
genius> 1-((3/4)^4)
= 
175
---
256
```

or

```
genius> 10/54
= 5/27
```

How do I get the answers as a normal floating point/decimal number?
For example `5/27 = 0.185185185185`

Comment: It'd be great if someone could add genius/GEL https://www.jirka.org/genius.html as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float()` to turn a number into a float. It is listed in the `Numeric` section of the help.

> genius> help float
>   float (x)
>   Description: Make number a float

```
genius> 5/27
= 5/27
genius> float(ans)
= 0.185185185185
genius> float(5/27)
= 0.185185185185
```

From the [manual](https://www.jirka.org/genius-reference.pdf) in 5.1.1 Numbers, you will see that a division will create a special number type, a `rational`. You can avoid this by having one or both operands as floats, simply by appending `.0`.

```
genius> 5.0/27
= 0.185185185185
```